# Display japanese text came from database in php

Tags: php, database, character-encoding

Recently I worked in a project in where I need to display japanese text which are come from database. I already use

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

It help to display the static text. But when it come from database it display "??????????" type text.

How can I solve this kind of problem?

Comment: What character set is the database using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the database charset `UTF8` too? Is the connection charset `UTF8`? Seems like the data gets converted to `ISO-8859-1` somewhere along the way.

Without more information, it is hard to find exactly what the problem is. What DBMS are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Either way, I'm pretty sure either your database and/or your connection isn't using `UTF8`.

You can change your connection charset by using one of the following functions:

```
mysql_set_charset('UTF-8');
pg_set_client_encoding('UTF-8');
```

Comment: Database MySQL. I use UTF8 in database.

Comment: Then use `mysql_set_charset()` to make the connection **UTF-8**.

Comment: Check the database locale and table locale.